# On a single node Swarm cluster, how can I use the on-failure restart policy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm trying to deploy a Docker stack to a Swarm composed of a single node only. I have two requirements that seem to conflict:

- I want to use the `on-failure` restart policy as I have a 3rd party tool stopping and restarting containers from time to time for taking backups
- I want my cluster to survive a node reboot without manual intervention

Currently, when I use the `on-failure` restart policy and reboot the host node, only the services that exit non-zero will be restarted by Swarm, the ones that exit zero will have a "Desired State: Shutdown".

When using `compose` I can achieve what I want using `restart: unless-stopped` in conjunction with `live-restore: true`, but this does not exist in Swarm mode.

When in Swarm mode, I can use a restart policy of `any` and have swarm restart services after reboot, but then I cannot use the backup tool.

Is there any way I can configure my services so that Swarm will restart them after a clean exit on reboot without having to use the `any` restart policy?